# Why is the Ricci scalar the only independent scalar constructed from products of the metric and its first and second derivatives?

Tags: general-relativity, differential-geometry, tensor-calculus, curvature, invariants

In Sean Carroll's book, last paragraph of page 160, this statement is found:

> "The Riemann tensor is of course made from the second derivatives of the metric, and we argued earlier that the only independent scalar we could construct from the Riemann tensor was the Ricci scalar R. What we did not show, but is nevertheless true, is that any nontrivial tensor made from products of the metric and its first and second derivatives can be expressed in terms of the metric and the Riemann tensor. Therefore, the only independent scalar constructed from the metric, which is no higher than second order in its derivatives, is the Ricci scalar."

What is the detailed proof of this statement?

Comment: The Riemann tensor is the unique tensor built out of two derivatives of the metric - https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/315374/. The Ricci scalar is the unique scalar that can be built out of the Riemann tensor.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [On the uniqueness of the Riemann-Christoffel tensor](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/315374/)