# Riemann curvature tensor is the only tensor that you can write down that has two derivatives of the metric tensor

Tags: general-relativity, differential-geometry, metric-tensor, tensor-calculus, curvature

Is the statement in the main question correct? Can someone send me a proof (link, pdf file etc.)

Comment: Yes it is. "Gravitation and Cosmology" Steven Weinberg, page:134

Comment: Also related: Lovelock's theorem (see for example the article on wikipedia)

Comment: No (you need some more conditions on your statement), e.g. all its contractions, Weyl tensor, etc.

Comment: Related and possibly a duplicate of an old question of mine: [On the uniqueness of the Riemann-Christoffel tensor](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/315374/on-the-uniqueness-of-the-riemann-christoffel-tensor).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can prove this by moving to Riemann normal coordinates at a point $p$. In these coordinates
$$
g_{ij}(p) = \eta_{ij} , \qquad \partial_k g_{ij}(p) = 0 , \qquad \partial_k \partial_l g_{ij}(p) = \frac{1}{3} [ R_{ikjl}(p) + R_{jkil}(p) ] . 
$$
It is then clear that anything that contains 2 metric derivatives can be re-written in terms of the Riemann tensor.