# Form of the trace of the energy-momentum tensor in 2D spacetime

Tags: general-relativity, conformal-field-theory, stress-energy-momentum-tensor, trace

I'm going over this article by [Davies](https://www.jstor.org/stable/79191), in which he derives the form of the energy-momentum tensor (emt) in 2D spacetime assuming a non vanishing trace anomaly.
He considers a metric of the form
$$
ds^2=C(u,v) du dv
$$
then argues that:

1. the trace $T^\mu_\mu$ should be functions of quadratic derivative of $C(u,v)$ due to dimensional analysis;
2. that $C(u,v)$ must be a function of both $u,v$ in order to have a curved spacetime, and therefore the trace will be a function of $\partial_u\partial_v C$ and $\partial_u C \partial_v C$
3. quoting from the article

> Because the theory does not contain a characteristic length, a simple rescaling argument shows that $T^\mu_\mu$ must be a homogeneous functional in $C$ of degree $-1$. Consequently$$T^\mu_\mu=aC^{-2}\partial_u\partial_v C+ b C^{-3}\partial_u C \partial_v C$$

where $a,b$ are some numerical factor which he fixes later using physical considerations.

While I understand the first two constraints, I'm having troubles wrapping my mind around the third. Why the trace should have that particular form?

Comment: How about something like this: if $u$ and $v$ are dimensionless, then since $[ds^2] = [L]^2$ we see $[C] = [L]^2$, and since $[T_{\mu \nu}] = [L]^{-2}$ we see that, since $[\partial_{uv}^2 C] = [L]^2$ we must have $[C^{-2}\partial_{uv}^2 C] = [L]^{-2}$, and since $[\partial_{u} C \partial_{v} C] = [L]^2$ we must have $[C^{-3}\partial_{u} C \partial_{v} C] = [L]^{-2}$.

Comment: @bolbteppa but why $u$ and $v$ are dimensionless? they are coordinates, so from my understanding they have $[u,v]=[L]$, while $C$ is dimensionless and $[\partial_u C]=[L]^{-1}$

Comment: Right, but from $ds^2 = C(u,v)dudv$ if we shift the units from $du$ and $dv$ into the $C(u,v)$ factor, so that $du$ and $dv$ become dimensionless, then $[\partial_u C] = [L]^2$ and $[\partial_{uv}^2 C] = [L]^2$ so $[C^{-2}\partial_{uv}^2 C] = [L]^{-2}$ etc... , maybe this is what he means by 'the theory does not contain a characteristic length' that the length is taken away from $u$ and $v$ and put into the conformal factor $C$.

Comment: @bolbteppa you mean something like introduce new coordinates, call them $\mu,\nu$ st $[\mu]=[\nu]=[L]^0$. But in order to make them dimensionless they should be defined as $u=\mu /ell$, where $\ell$ is some parameter st $[\ell]=[L]^2$, and similar for $\nu$. At this point you can define a new conformal factor $D(\mu,\nu)=C(u,v)\ell^2$ and the line element becomes $d s^2=D(\mu,nu)d\mu d\nu$. The new conformal factor has dimension $[D]=[L]^2$, so what you said in the first comment would work, but what is $\ell$? I don't have any characteristic length in the theory.

Comment: It's simpler than that, $ds^2[L]^2 = C(u,v) \frac{[L]^2}{[L]^2} du[L] dv[L] = C(u,v)[L]^2 du[L]^0 dv[L]^0$, i.e. you literally just move the ignorable $[L]^2$ from $du dv [L]^2$ to $C(u,v)$, whatever you're trying to do, that $\mathcal{l}$ is on both sides, it's in front of the $ds^2$ too, so it should cancel out on both sides, the way $[L]^2$ cancels out on both sides of $ds^2 [L]^2 = C(u,v)[L]^2 du dv$ or of $ds^2 [L]^2 = C(u,v)du[L] dv[L]$, I think this is enough, if someone else has something better (I doubt it) we'll see.

Comment: Oh ok now I understand what you're saying, thanks you for clarifying. It's the first time I see something like that, is something you can actually do?

Comment: The problem with making $u$ and $v$ dimensionless is that this would allow you to use as many derivatives as you want. If none of Davies' arguments use difffeomorphism invariance (the actual way you show that $T_\mu^\mu \propto R$) then I don't trust his paper.

Comment: He actually provides an *independent* argument for why it only contains $\partial_u C \partial_v C$ and $\partial^2_{uv} C$ above equation (5) (from asking what happens if $C$ is a function of only one variable, whether it's correct is another question I guess) i.e. he appears to claim that you can't add as many derivatives as you want, which maybe makes it more likely what I said was right.

Comment: All he proves is that there needs to be at least one $u$ derivative and one $v$ derivative. Ruling out $\partial_u^{99} C \partial_v^{99} C$ requires $u$ and $v$ to have dimensions of length.

Comment: @ConnorBehan could you point me out some references on the difffeomorphism invariance argument?

Comment: Classifying the invariants with two derivatives is discussed at https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/665496/riemann-curvature-tensor-is-the-only-tensor-that-you-can-write-down-that-has-two

Comment: Don't think that makes any sense or even applies and is just confusing things with handwaving, what I said seems good enough, I'm out.

Comment: @ConnorBehan i may have a solution, but i don't feel really sure about it. i answered my question to include all the details

Answer (score 0):

A generic way of reaching the equation you quote (though it will need calculation) could be using the Einstein equations

$R^{ab} - \frac{1}{2}g^{ab}R = T^{ab}$ ,

where the symbols have their usual meaning. I will roughly outline the steps for you:

1. Since you are after ${T^a}_b$ you can use the inverse metric ($g_{ab}$) to lower and index and then take the trace by matching the indices.
2. Now, you would need to calculate (simplify) the expression on the LHS of this equation. Remember, for you, in components $g^{ab} = C$ and $g_{ab} = C^{-1}$.
3. The [Ricci tensor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ricci_curvature) can be written in terms of the Christoffel symbols and their derivatives as
   $R_{ab} := \partial_c\Gamma_{ab}^c - \partial_a\Gamma_{bc}^a + \Gamma_{cd}^a\Gamma_{bc}^d - \Gamma_{bd}^c\Gamma_{cb}^d.$
   But the article you quote states that the only non-vanished ones are ${\Gamma^c}_{cc}$ so that helps.
4. Also the Ricci scalar is $R = g_{ab}R^{ab}$ and the [Christoffel symbols](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Christoffel_symbols) can be derived from the metric as

${\Gamma^d}_{ab}
  = \frac{1}{2} g^{cd} \left(\frac{\partial g_{ca}}{\partial x^b} + \frac{\partial g_{cb}}{\partial x^a} - \frac{\partial g_{ab}}{\partial x^c} \right)$

Comment: I'm in two dimensions, so when contracting with the inverse metri  the LHS reads $R-\frac22 R=0$, and hence $T^a_a=0$

Comment: I think you want to contract only on 1-index, i.e. $g_{ac}R^{ab} - \frac{1}{2}g_{ac}g^{ab}R = g_{ac}T^{ab}$. Your LHS should remain a (1,1) tensor to match the RHS. Then you take the trace.

Comment: And then set $b=c$?